# Align image and text inside li - multiple lines, restrictive space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a menu for a mobile with 200px width (yeah... just 200px). So I'm restrictive in space.

So I'm creating the menu with ul's and li's. Inside each one there is an icon and the description text.

The problem is... I need to align the icons with the descriptions. But with so muuuuch space (not) the text is just breaking down and the second word goes above the respective icon.

I can't use tables... neither the trick of put the icon inside a bigger div to deluve the description. (I'm not sure of the description and icon that will fit there when it passes to the next person.)

So... can you help me? I leave here my code. Thanks so much!

### Snippet

```css
#principal{
  max-width:600px;
  width:200px;
  height:2000px;
  margin:0 auto;

  background-color:black;
  background-image:url(images/header_background.png);
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center top;

  overflow:hidden;
}
#footer{
  color:white;
  padding:0px 10px;
}

#menu3{
  color:#c2c2c3;
  font-size:12px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  list-style:none;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}

#menu3 ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menu3 img{
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right:8px;
}
div ul li span{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#menu3 li a{
  color:#c2c2c3;
}

#menu3 li a:hover, #menu3 li a:hover img{
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">
  <div id="footer">
    <ul id="menu3">
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/responsabilidade.png" /><span>responsabilidade social</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/horario.png" /> <span>horário</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/localizacao.png" /> <span>localização</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/contactos.png" /> <span>contactos</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/mapaSite.png" /> <span>mapa do site</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/creditos.png" /> <span>créditos</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are the icons fixed or variable width?

Comment: If icons have a fixed width, see the NiZa answer. If not, see the silviagreen answer.

Comment: The icons are fixed, what maybe change is the text.

Comment: so your solution is the NiZa answer.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Problem: I didnt understood what (s)he have done. =X

Comment: Yeah, it's a problem because she don't explain how to make it, but her code works. I add a comment with an explanation with what she is making.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I assumed with an image height and width of 30 pixels.

```css
#principal {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url(images/header_background.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#footer {
  color: white;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

#menu3 {
  color: #c2c2c3;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu3 img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

div ul li span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#menu3 li {
  padding-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 30px;
}

#menu3 li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#menu3 li a img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#menu3 li a {
  color: #c2c2c3;
}

#menu3 li a:hover,
#menu3 li a:hover img {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">
      <div id="footer">
        <ul id="menu3">
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/responsabilidade.png" /><span>responsabilidade social</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/horario.png" /> <span>horário</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/localizacao.png" /> <span>localização</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/contactos.png" /> <span>contactos</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/mapaSite.png" /> <span>mapa do site</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/creditos.png" /> <span>créditos</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I didn't understood what you have done. =X Sorry.

ps: The image was already 30*30px;

Comment: This is a correct answer, according with your requirements and let icons fixed width. That NiZa makes here is to put the icon with absolute positioning to the left corner, and then make the `<li>` with a padding of `30 + 10 = 40` to move the text. There are more ways to make this, but this is a correct solution.

Comment: Hope Marcos Pérez Gude explanation helps you understand. If you need any improvements or help just let me know.

Comment: Thanks so much @MarcosPérezGude, and NiZa too. :)

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution: remove padding left and use `white-space:nowrap;` to force icon and text stay on the same line

```css
#principal{
  max-width:600px;
  width:200px;
  height:2000px;
  margin:0 auto;

  background-color:black;
  background-image:url(images/header_background.png);
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center top;

  overflow:hidden;
}
#footer{
  color:white;
  padding:0px 10px;
}

#menu3{
  color:#c2c2c3;
  font-size:12px; 
  text-transform:uppercase;
  list-style:none;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  padding-left: 0; /*remove padding*/
}

#menu3 ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

#menu3 img{
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right:8px;
}
div ul li span{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#menu3 li a{
  color:#c2c2c3;
}

#menu3 li a:hover, #menu3 li a:hover img{
  opacity: 0.8;
}

li{
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">
  <div id="footer">
    <ul id="menu3">
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/responsabilidade.png" /><span>responsabilidade social</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/horario.png" /> <span>horário</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/localizacao.png" /> <span>localização</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/contactos.png" /> <span>contactos</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/mapaSite.png" /> <span>mapa do site</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/creditos.png" /> <span>créditos</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, what about if the text is too long even with less font size? That's not the solution, is a visual hack.

Comment: It makes sense, even white-space can break the layout, but your attemp is aprox. If the icons have a fixed width it's better the solution of @NiZa. But I upvote you :)

Comment: OP is missing, so maybe you need to wait hours or days or weeks to know if it solves the OP's problem

Comment: OP === person who ask the question in this post.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude the max thing I can do is to put all text in same line but all text goes above the icon. =X